Как сделать чтобы писало ник человека который вошел в чат
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def new_member(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    
bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //начните с заголовка пожалуйста

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def new_member(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    for new_member in message.new_chat_members:
        username = new_member.username if new_member.username else "без ника"
        welcome_message = f"Добро пожаловать, {username}!"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome_message)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

Если ты об этом

Да спасибо! Он работает без проблем
